# Rotate 2 sided image

Tags: android, matrix, camera, image-rotation

please help to rotate 2 sided image(like coin) - animation of swap of sides, when the first image is visible, the second is not. When I rotate image, until angle of rotation is less than 90 degrees I show the first image, the second image otherwise.

Now, its rotated over Y axis (A), but I need rotate image over axis - center of rotated image (B).

Transformations:

```
long aniAngle = (System.currentTimeMillis() - animationStart)*180/ANIMATION_TIME;
     aniCamera.save();

            if(aniAngle <= 90)
            {                   
                aniCamera.rotateY(aniAngle); // angle of current rotation
                aniCamera.getMatrix(aniMatrix);
                                    aniCamera.restore();

                int centerX = x + image.getWidth()/2;
                int centerY = y + iamge.getHeight()/2;              

                aniMatrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
                aniMatrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
                                    canvas.save();
                                    canvas.concat(aniMatrix);
  Bitmap image = angle < 90 ? image1 : image2;
 if(image == image2)
    angle = 180 - angle; // second image goes from rotated state to normal - degrees of rotation should decrease during animation
```

c.translate(x + image.getWidth()/2, y + cover.getHeight()/2); // image left top corner with coords (x,y)

```
        c.rotate(angle); // angle of rotation non animated image        

        c.drawBitmap(image, -image.getWidth()/2, -image.getHeight()/2, null);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCRde.png

Comment: If you solve this problem, then can you post you answer here? Because am also stuck on this problem...!!!